# Wildfly 10 HTTPS certificate fine on 8443 but on 443 says bad certificate

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly-10

I am trying to configure Wildfly (10) to use an SSL certificate for HTTPS.   It seems to work fine for 8443 (using https://example.com:8443 -- no errors and certificate shows it is signed by the CA), but when I switch the HTTPS to port 443, whenever I access the site (via   https://example.com  it tells me my certificate was not installed right, the connection is not secure and it's using a self-signed key).

Here are snippets from my standalone.xml file:

Security Realm

> ```
>        <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
>             <server-identities>
>                 <ssl>
>                     <keystore path="devifs.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="yadayada" alias="tomcat" key-password="yadayada"/>
>                 </ssl>
>             </server-identities>
>             <authentication>
>                 <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
>                 <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authentication>
>             <authorization>
>                 <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
>             </authorization>
>         </security-realm>
> ```

Undertow Subsystem

> ```
>    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.0">
>         <buffer-cache name="default"/>
>         <server name="default-server">
>             <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
>             <https-listener name="default-ssl" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" socket-binding="https"/>
>             <host name="default-host" default-web-module="hatteras.war" alias="localhost">
>                 <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
>                 <location name="/reports/" handler="ifsreports"/>
>                 <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
>                 <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
>             </host>
>          </server>
>             ....
>      </subsystem>
> ```

Socket Binding Group

> ```
> <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
>     <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
>     <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
>     <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
>     <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
>     <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:443}"/>
>     <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
>     <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
>     <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
>         <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
>     </outbound-socket-binding>
> </socket-binding-group>
> ```

I've restarted Wildfly and even the server after making the standalone.xml changes.   No luck.

Stack:

- Wildfly 10.0.0.final
- Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
- AWS

Any suggestions?

Comment: My SSL contact pointed out that JBoss cannot run on 443 because it's a privileged port.  This lead me to research and I found I should redirect the port using:      **iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443**      Is this the correct method?   Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My SSL contact pointed out that JBoss cannot run on 443 because it's a privileged port. This lead me to research and I found I should redirect the port using: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443 Is this the correct method? Seems to work fine.

Comment: I've had to do it before so I think under the circumstances it's the correct method for you if you don't have a load balancer like and F5 to redirect port 443 to 8443

Comment: Thank you also for the sort version of getting https setup as compared to RedHats pages and pages of information thats not quite to the point!

Comment: That's correct but you should run this command after each reboot